# How to find a duplicate element in a nested list then add the contents of the duplicate to the original list

Tags: python

Say I have the nested list:

```
[
['Algeria', 1,2,3,4],
['Chad', 2,3,4,5],
['Chad', 3,4,5,6],
['Chad', 1,2,3,4],
['USA', 5,6,7,8]
]
```

How do I make it so when there is a duplicate country, we add the values of the duplicate list to the original? For example the output should look like this:

```
[
['Algeria', 1,2,3,4],
['Chad', 6,9,12,15],
['USA', 5,6,7,8]
]
```

Comment: what blocks you ?

Comment: Are duplicate countries consecutive, or can they be anywhere in the original list?

Comment: The duplicate countries are consecutive!

Comment: if consecutive this is more simple, you do not even have to use a dict for instance to save list for each name beginning lists. So just iterate to detect same name and when needed iterate to add then remove not wanted or create a new one (to avoid to modify a list you iterate in). If we do for you you will learn nothing, better you do yourself, so put a proposal even not perfect

Comment: For future reference, it may be easier to work with tabular data like this if you originally store it in a dataframe with pandas

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following, using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * 4)
for country, *vals in l:
    d[country] = map(sum, zip(d[country], vals))

result = [[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()]
# [['Algeria', 1, 2, 3, 4], 
#  ['Chad', 6, 9, 12, 15], 
#  ['USA', 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use `pandas` here. Using [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(l) #l is your list
df.groupby(0, as_index=False).sum().values.tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[['Algeria', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['Chad', 6, 9, 12, 15], ['USA', 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple `for` loop to iterate through items in the given list `L` simultaneously using a `dictionary` to keep track of the iterated counties, if there is the duplicated county we add the values of that county to the values stored in dictionary.

**Try this:**

```
info = {}
for sublist in L:
    key = sublist[0]
    if key not in info:
        info[key] = sublist[1:]
    else:
        info[key] = [(a+ b) for a, b in zip(sublist[1:], info[key])]

result = [[k, *v] for k, v in info.items()]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Algeria', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['Chad', 6, 9, 12, 15], ['USA', 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: the OP said in a comment "The duplicate countries are consecutive! " so you do not need a dict, just to save the previous case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dictionary instead of a nested list for such cases.

However, this can solve your problem.

**Code**

```py
old_list = [['Algeria', 1,2,3,4], ['Chad', 2,3,4,5], ['Chad', 3,4,5,6],
 ['Chad', 1,2,3,4], ['USA', 5,6,7,8]]

new_list = []
for element in old_list:
  if element[0] not in ['' if len(element) == 0 else element[0] for element in new_list]:
    new_list.append(element)

  else:
    for new_element in new_list:
      if element[0] == new_element[0]:
        new_element[1] += element[1]
        new_element[2] += element[2]
        new_element[3] += element[3]
        new_element[4] += element[4]

print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
[['Algeria', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['Chad', 6, 9, 12, 15], ['USA', 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```